# Deleting from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to delete rows from two tables which are related by id. I am doing the delete using checkboxes, for checked rows delete all.

The below code deletes from both table but when I check two results it will delete two of them from table one but only deletes one row from table two. How can be able to delete multiple rows from both table? `foreach` worked on the first query but it doesn't work on the second query.

can someone give me a hint?

```
     <?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $select = $mydb->prepare("select * FROM search where username = ?  and id = ? ");
        echo $mydb->error;
        foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
            $select->bind_param('ss', $username->username, $id);
            $select->execute();
            $data = $select->get_result();
            while ($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
                $pdata = $row['productID'];
                if ($row['producttype'] == 'laptop') {
                    $smt = $mydb->prepare("DELETE from search where username = ? and id = ?");
                    echo $mydb->error;
                    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
                        $smt->bind_param('ss', $username->username, $id);
                        $smt->execute();
                        $smt->close();

                        $smtr = $mydb->prepare("DELETE from laptops where username = ? and id = ?");
                        echo $mydb->error;
                        foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id) {   // foreach was supposed to work but it doesn't work here I don't know why. it works on the first query.
                            $smtr->bind_param('ss', $username->username, $pdata); //$pdata from 1st query == id from second query.
                            $smtr->execute();
                        }
                        $smtr->close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" class="styled-button-8" value="Delete">
    <?php
    $search = $mydb->prepare("select * from search where username = ? order by id");
    $search->bind_param('s', $username->username);
    $search->execute();
    $res = $search->get_result();
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id[]"  class="check" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
            <?php
            echo $row['title'];
            echo $row['description'];
        }
        ?>
</form>
```

Comment: You are missing/misplacing a few } to start with

Comment: @TomToms is that why only one row is being deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example...

```
 SELECT * FROM recipes;
 +-----------+-------------------------+
 | recipe_id | recipe                  |
 +-----------+-------------------------+
 |         1 | Macaroni & Cheese       |
 |         2 | Cheese on Toast         |
 |         3 | Beans on Toast          |
 |         4 | Cheese & Beans on Toast |
 |         5 | Toast & Jam             |
 |         6 | Bananas                 |
 +-----------+-------------------------+

 SELECT * FROM ingredients;
 +---------------+------------+
 | ingredient_id | ingredient |
 +---------------+------------+
 |             1 | Macaroni   |
 |             2 | Cheese     |
 |             3 | Beans      |
 |             4 | Toast      |
 |             5 | Jam        |
 |             6 | Bananas    |
 +---------------+------------+

 SELECT * FROM recipe_ingredient;
 +-----------+---------------+
 | recipe_id | ingredient_id |
 +-----------+---------------+
 |         1 |             1 |
 |         1 |             2 |
 |         2 |             2 |
 |         2 |             4 |
 |         3 |             3 |
 |         3 |             4 |
 |         4 |             2 |
 |         4 |             3 |
 |         4 |             4 |
 |         5 |             4 |
 |         5 |             5 |
 |         6 |             6 | <-- The popular recipe 'Bananas' is made from bananas
 +-----------+---------------+

 SELECT r.*, i.* 
   FROM recipes r 
   JOIN recipe_ingredient ri 
     ON ri.recipe_id = r.recipe_id 
   JOIN ingredients i 
     ON i.ingredient_id = ri.ingredient_id;
 +-----------+-------------------------+---------------+------------+
 | recipe_id | recipe                  | ingredient_id | ingredient |
 +-----------+-------------------------+---------------+------------+
 |         1 | Macaroni & Cheese       |             1 | Macaroni   |
 |         1 | Macaroni & Cheese       |             2 | Cheese     |
 |         2 | Cheese on Toast         |             2 | Cheese     |
 |         2 | Cheese on Toast         |             4 | Toast      |
 |         3 | Beans on Toast          |             3 | Beans      |
 |         3 | Beans on Toast          |             4 | Toast      |
 |         4 | Cheese & Beans on Toast |             2 | Cheese     |
 |         4 | Cheese & Beans on Toast |             3 | Beans      |
 |         4 | Cheese & Beans on Toast |             4 | Toast      |
 |         5 | Toast & Jam             |             4 | Toast      |
 |         5 | Toast & Jam             |             5 | Jam        |
 |         6 | Bananas                 |             6 | Bananas    | <-- See?
 +-----------+-------------------------+---------------+------------+
```

So, now let's delete both the recipe and the ingredient from the database, but just for fun let's keep the '6,6' relationship in the recipe_ingredient table...

```
 DELETE r
      , i
   FROM recipes r
   JOIN recipe_ingredient ri
     ON ri.recipe_id = r.recipe_id
   JOIN ingredients i
     ON i.ingredient_id = ri.ingredient_id
  WHERE recipe = 'Bananas';

 Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)


 SELECT * FROM recipes;
 +-----------+-------------------------+
 | recipe_id | recipe                  |
 +-----------+-------------------------+
 |         1 | Macaroni & Cheese       |
 |         2 | Cheese on Toast         |
 |         3 | Beans on Toast          |
 |         4 | Cheese & Beans on Toast |
 |         5 | Toast & Jam             |
 +-----------+-------------------------+

 SELECT * FROM ingredients;
 +---------------+------------+
 | ingredient_id | ingredient |
 +---------------+------------+
 |             1 | Macaroni   |
 |             2 | Cheese     |
 |             3 | Beans      |
 |             4 | Toast      |
 |             5 | Jam        |
 +---------------+------------+

 SELECT * FROM recipe_ingredient;
 +-----------+---------------+
 | recipe_id | ingredient_id |
 +-----------+---------------+
 |         1 |             1 |
 |         1 |             2 |
 |         2 |             2 |
 |         2 |             4 |
 |         3 |             3 |
 |         3 |             4 |
 |         4 |             2 |
 |         4 |             3 |
 |         4 |             4 |
 |         5 |             4 |
 |         5 |             5 |
 |         6 |             6 | <-- Still here!
 +-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Okay I am not quite understanding the example. so are you saying that it isn't possible to delete from the second query?

Comment: I'm saying that you only need one query.

Comment: Thanks but it is easier for me to work with two queries, I don't get `JOIN`, `ON`. do you have suggestion for my problem?